# Align tables next to each other, in a scrolled container

Tags: css, html-table, css-float

Is it possible to align 2 tables next to each other, even if the first table is wider than the window?

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XqSJG/69/

I've tried:

```
display:inline-block;
float:left;
```

But evidently, that's not the right approach.

It seems, the second table is always moved to the next line, as long as the first table is at least 100% wide. This obviously makes sense in most cases, but the data I'm showing in the second one is related to that in the first one.

Is it possible to force the second table to show up next to the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the tables within an overarching table, within a wrapper which scrolls.

If you give the tables themselves large sizes...**[they still wont wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/XqSJG/74/)**

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/XqSJG/74/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class='column'>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>t1</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
            <!-- blah -->
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>t2</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                    <td>col text blah blah blah</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#355E95;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.content {
    display:table;
}
.column {
    display:table-cell;
}
table {
    width:1500px;
}
```